# Incorrect page rendering on first draw

Tags: html, css

I'm building a webpsite but it has a weird issue. When I first navigate to the page, it will render the menu outside the header. When I refresh the page or navigate to another page (with the same HTML) it will display correctly.

I suspect it has to do with the image in the header and the browser (both IE10 and Chrome) reserving the entire width for it on initial load.

## HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" />
    <ul id="menu">...</ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
img#logo {
    height: 61px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 3.09em;
}
#menu {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
}
```

When I put `#menu` before `#logo` the issue is solved but it feels weird to do that. Anyone knows the precise reason why this happens? Can it be solved with CSS change?

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MA286/3/)** (Can only reproduce on server, not in Fiddle but it helps to illustrate)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `float:left;` property to your logo selector the isusue is solved.

```
img#logo {
    height: 61px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 1em;
    float:left;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5LYPs/)